# incrementing unsigned char *image

Tags: c#, c++, casting, char, unsigned

```
void draw(unsigned char *image)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
            {
                if (someCondition)
                {
                    int red = x * 256 / WIDTH;
                    int green = 255;
                    int blue = y * 256 / HEIGHT;

                    image[0] = (unsigned char)blue;
                    image[1] = (unsigned char)green;
                    image[2] = (unsigned char)red;
                }
                else
                {
                    image[0] = 0;
                    image[1] = 0;
                    image[2] = 0;
                }
                image += 3;
            }
        }
    }
```

What does incrementing image+=3; actually do here. I'm trying to convert the same c++ code to C#, but unable to achieve this. I'm using byte[] image in C#, now how should I do image+=3 in C#. Is it scaling the image?

Comment: It's pointer arithmetic. In C# you will probably want to use an index variable instead

Comment: My C++ is a little rusty, but i think it is incrementing the index by 3 (so image points to next pixel)

Comment: When it comes to language translations, doing direct translations almost never turns out well. It doesn't matter if the languages are spoken, written or programming. For programming languages, it's often better to reimplement the algorithms instead of translating the code. Or perhaps even go further back and start over with the design and build the program from the start.

Comment: @UnholySheep Sorry, I'm not understanding the concept, do I need to skip 3 index and fill next pixel?

Comment: Each pixel is three bytes. You need to skip over three bytes to get to the next pixel.

Comment: @UnholySheepI think I got it, it's skipping three addresses in the memory, and filling up next address. What confused me is image[0]. So when we skip three addresses even image[0] is the current pixel after skipping and image[1] is next pixel in queue, Am I right?

Comment: @DeebashVFX each pixel is 3 bytes (1 for each RGB color). `image` pointer points to the current pixel address, so image[0] is the first byte of the current pixel, image[1] is the second and image[2] the third

Comment: @Magnetron Thanks, I understood it now. I have one more question, in a DLL exported function (const void *image); Do I need to pass byte[] image from C# or Do I need to create IntPtr for the array and pass it.

Comment: Whatever this code is trying to do, it's not very good C++ code (pointer arithmetic is discouraged) and definitely not good C# code. It's also slow. It's slower than using the [GDI recoloring transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-a-color-matrix-to-transform-a-single-color?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) or the SIMD operations of [the System.Numerics vectors and matrices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.matrix3x2?view=net-7.0)

Comment: @DeebashVFX what are you trying to do? This code won't perform faster than normal C# code but can easily result in buffer overflows.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ignore the above posted code. I want to push byte[] image array to exported dll function which was written in c++. When I execute the c++ code directly all are working. But when I create extern function and call it from C#, image data is not coming in c++ code. 

In c++:
extern "C" void scSendFrame(scCamera* camera, const void* image_bits);

In C#: When I pass byte[] image like scSendFrame(cameraPtr, image); values are not received in the c++ end.

So what I'm asking is Am I passing the values correctly or I need to create IntPtr in C# for the byte array to send.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code it is evident that the pointer points to an element of an array of `unsigned char`:

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ] ........... [ ]

 ^
 |
 image
```

Next consider that `image[i]` is equivalent (really equivalent, that is how it is defined) to `*(image + i)`, ie it increments the pointer by `i` and dereferences it. You can write `image[0]` to get the element `image` points to. You can type `image[1]` to get the next element in the array.

Lets call the actual array `x` then you can access its elements via incrementing `image` like this:

```
x[0]      x[1]     x[2]      x[3]          x[4]          x[5]
image[0]  image[1] image[2]
                             (image+3)[0]  (image+3)[1]  (image+3)[2]
```

In other words, the author could have used some `offset` in the outer loop which increments by 3 in each iteration and then instead of `image[ i ]` they would have used `image[ i + offset ]`. Instead they choose to increment `image` which has the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code in C# with comments which hopefully help understand what is done.
I highly recommend reading [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/image-stride) about image strides.

I read in the comments that each pixel has 3-byte which is why it is incremented by 3... while this might be true for some images, it is overall wrong. The bytes per pixel are depended on the pixel format of the image. you image can have 1-byte per pixel, 2-byte per pixel, 3-byte per pixel, 4-byte per pixel. The byte per pixel are also known as [Color depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace something 
{
    
    void draw(Bitmap bmp) 
    {
        BitmapData data = null;
        try {
            // Returns an object of type BitmapData.
            // BitmapData object grants you access 
            // to the address of the first pixel.
            data = bmp.UnlockBits(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                bmp.PixelFormat);
                
            unsafe {
                // Byte per pixel.
                // This is really import!
                // By checking how many bytes a pixel consumes
                // you know how to increment your raw pixel data.
                int bpp = Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(data.PixelFormat) / 8;
                // Pointer to the first pixel.
                byte* ptFirst = (byte*)data.Scan0;
                // Using a parallel loop here 
                // drastically improves performance.
                Parallel.For(0, data.Height, y => 
                {
                    // Get the pointer of the first pixel
                    // in the current stride.
                    // If you imagine your image as a table with 
                    // rows and columns, then this is the 'index'
                    // of the row.
                    // Images are built from multiple strides (rows).
                    byte* pixel = ptFirst + (y * data.Stride);
                    // IMPORTANT: Incrementing by byte-per-pixel 
                    // is crucial here as you need to skip n-bytes 
                    // to get to the next pixel.
                    // The pixel count per stride is the
                    // width multiplied by byte-per-pixel.
                    for (int x=0; x<data.Stride; x+=bpp) 
                    {
                        if (someCondition) {
                            // Calc some colour values.
                            byte r = (byte)(x*256/data.Width);
                            byte g = byte.MaxValue;
                            byte b = (byte)(y*256/data.Height);
                            // Assign colour.
                            pixel[x+2]=r;   
                            pixel[x+1]=g;
                            pixel[x+0]=b;
                        }
                        else {
                            // Set pixel to black.
                            pixel[x+2]=0;   
                            pixel[x+1]=0;
                            pixel[x+0]=0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (null != data) {
                bmp.UnlockBits(data);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```